# DirectX - Stop rendering to lessen amount of resources used?

Tags: optimization, resources, directx, hook

Recently I've been writing a bot for a game which uses a DirectX backend for its rendering. I have managed to 'hack' the game into allowing me to run multiple instances. Unfortunately, this has taken a serious toll on my computer's CPU/RAM usage. I would like to optimize & reduce the amount of resources each instance eats up. Thus, I have a couple of questions:

- If I stop DirectX from rendering, will this increase performance?
- How can I do so?

I have a few ideas about how to do this - I'm guessing I can just hook the rendering function and force it to return without doing anything. My question though - **will doing so noticeably improve performance?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: No, immediately returning from the render call will not reduce CPU load, because you're then busy-waiting. You have to manipulate your main loop such that it does a wait for input or for a small timeout each time. That gives time to the other instances. In a first attempt, you could just pack a Sleep(some small amount) in there. Of course, that reduces the FPS of each instance, but it will allow other applications to run more smoothly.

And secondly: No, if you reduce the frame rate, the RAM usage will not be less. To reduce the memory load, you'll need to find more sophisticated ways, like removing textures when you don't need them any more etc.